# The best way to migrate production traffic from an external cloud to a Google Cloud project?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

I have an application running in a third party cloud and a mirror of it running in GCP. My DNS is handled internally by a ticketing system so it will transfer at some point 12-36 hours after I submit the ticket. What is the best way to migrate traffic over?

I thought I could point the DNS to google cloud load balancer and have that initially point to my third party cloud, with the option to slowly migrate to my google cloud project.

However, it appears that external backends are not an option in the google load balancer. Is the best option then to do this with Nginx inside my google or external cloud by creating a re-route path?

Due to the DNS time lag, that seems risky and not a preferred solution so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: What's you concern when you migration from external cloud to google ?
Is how to quickly rollback to external cloud when something  wrong in google ?